# Apply sobel filter for edge detection in emgucv

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I am trying to apply Sobel filter on my picture to  detect edges as you can see here :

```
Image<Gray, Byte> imgProcessed1;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    Image<Bgr, Byte> imgProcessed=new Image<Bgr, byte>(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\1.jpg");

    imgProcessed1 = imgProcessed.Convert<Gray, byte>();
    Image<Gray, Single> img_final = (imgProcessed1.Sobel(1, 0, 5));
    pictureBox1.Image = img_final.ToBitmap();
}
```

but the result is very unusual ,i am so new in opencv.

my output

[image]

I need this result.

[image]

i just need to apply this filter

[image]

Comment: You have to find the exact horizontal and vertical lines , so it is hard determine the exact parameters you need to run with Sobel.
I would suggest using Canny and then using the HoughLines operation to determine which lines are strong vertical and horzontal lines you can chose the angle by playing with variables.

Comment: @DeJaVo you know i want to apply both hor and ver filter on my picture to detect license plate.how can i do that ?could you please explain that in more details

Comment: First run Canny edge detection , then HoughLines in order to get the exact hor and ver lines. then use it on Sobel and to get the proper result play with the angle until you find the required output.

Comment: Let me know if that support your question, in case it is, I'll post it as answer and please mark it as solution.

Comment: @DeJaVo thank you dear friend i updated my post

Comment: Image<Bgr, Byte> imgProcessed=new Image<Bgr, byte>(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\1.jpg");

            Image<Gray, Byte> grayImage = imgProcessed.Convert<Gray, Byte>() ;
            grayImage.Canny(new Gray(10), new Gray(60));
            //grayImage.Sobel(int xorder, intyorder, int aptureSize)
            grayImage.Sobel(1, 0, 3);
            pictureBox1.Image = grayImage.ToBitmap();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99069/discussion-between-ehsan-akbar-and-dejavo).

Comment: you output image is signed data with positive and negavtive values coded to white and black so some gray is zero. convert to unsigned (absolute val) before displaying

Comment: @Micka how can i do that?

Comment: Sorry, no idea about c# emguCV syntax. Are you able to access each single pixel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

thank you all my friend ,i finally found a solution :

```
Image<Gray, byte> gray = new Image<Gray, byte>(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\1.jpg");
            Image<Gray, float> sobel = gray.Sobel(0, 1, 3).Add(gray.Sobel(1, 0, 3)).AbsDiff(new Gray(0.0));
            pictureBox1.Image = sobel.ToBitmap();
```

Comment: its simple like other edge detection but threshold is difrence color value between pixeles

Answer (score 2):

According to opencv documentation:

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html

you should use the sobel operator in the following way:

```
Sobel( src_gray, grad_x, ddepth, 1, 0, 3, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );
```

The function takes the following arguments:

1. src_gray: In our example, the input image. Here it is CV_8U
2. grad_x/grad_y: The output image.
3. ddepth: The depth of the output image. We set it to CV_16S to avoid
   overflow.
4. x_order: The order of the derivative in x direction.
5. y_order: The order of the derivative in y direction.
6. scale, delta and BORDER_DEFAULT: We use default values.

I hope it support you question.

Comment: thank you what about the values of the function i mean src_gray, grad_x, ddepth, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT

Comment: which values should i use ?

Comment: int scale = 1;
int delta = 0;
int ddepth = CV_16S;


The rest is written in my answer.

Comment: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.3.0.0/html/ba6758af-4c6b-fd85-638e-159c4c3ad8a6.htm

Comment: According to your documentation, you should use:
Sobel(1,2,3)